# Add comma and convert number to arabic number by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change latin number to arabic number and add comma in between each three arabic number by two jQuery function, i try it bum is a problem, in my code instead comma `,` between three number it put a `،`, (if active arabic language in your system you can see this problem) How can put between each three arabic number comma as `,`?

My regex in code is this: `/([^,]+)([^,]{3})/`

**See my full code and Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/d5LEK/

Comment: AFAIK, in Arabic numbers, `,` is used in place of decimal and cannot occur twice in a number.

Comment: In your demo I see `،` even though I've done nothing to set my system to support Arabic, but isn't that correct for that number system? (Also, in English, doesn't the term "Arabic numbers" usually mean just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.? And "Latin numbers" usually means the same as "Roman numerals", i.e, I, II, III, IV, V, etc.)